# Kibana 7.10 Dashboard Drilldown

Tags: elastic-stack, dashboard, drilldown, kibana-7

I've been playing with the new Create Drilldown feature available in Kibana 7.10 dashboards.

On the parent dashboard I have a stacked horizontal bar chart:

- The y-axis (i.e. bar label) is a "Site Name"
- The x-axis (i.e. bar length is count of documents)
- The bars are split by a "Reason Code" (two values).

I've got the drill down configured and working BUT when I select the drill down from a bar on the parent chart it takes me to the new dashboard automatically filtered by both "Site Name" and "Reason Code".

I would like to drill down with ONLY the "Site Name" filter selected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been confirmed by Elastic this option is not currently supported in the Dashboard Drilldown feature. Although it may be possible to achieve the required behaviour using the URL drilldown feature.